# Grounding through the earth pin on a 3-pin power plug

Tags: electrical

I want to ground some equipment that has only a 2-wire cord.

Is it safe to make a cable that has a wire connected to the earth pin of a 3-pin plug and use that as a grounding strap?

(This is NZ, but I guess the same would apply in most electrical codes).

Comment: Does this equipment have a "square-within-a-square" marking on it?  Also, is it in a metal box or a plastic one?

Comment: In the US they sell grounding straps which terminate in the standard mains 3-prong plug, you know the one.   Only the ground pin is connected to anything.

Comment: Metal, and double insulated ("square-within-a-square") - it's two SL1200 decks and a mixer. Which seem to act as a really good aerial to pick up mains noise.